# Prove that $f(1)-f(0)=\int_0^1 f'(t)dt$ using $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+o(h)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ a $\mathcal C^1([0,1])$ function. I want to prove that $$f(1)-f(0)=\int_0^1 f'(t)dt$$ using $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+o(h)$. In the official solution of my lecture they do as follow : Let $$0=x_0^n<x_1^n<...<x_{m_n-1}^n<x_{m_n}^n=1$$ a subdivision of $[0,1]$ s.t. $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\max_{i=1,...,m_n-1}\Delta x_i^n=0,$$
where $\Delta x_i^n=x_{i+1}^n-x_i^n$.

We have that $$f(1)-f(0)=\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}f(x_{i+1}^n)-f(x_i^n)$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}f(x_{i}^n)\Delta x_i^n+\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}o(\Delta x_i^n).$$
The first sum converges to $\int_0^1f'(t)dt$ and the second sum converges to $0$.

**Question :** I don't see why $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}o(\Delta x_i^n)=0.$$
Any idea ?

Comment: Use the generalized stokes theorem!

Comment: It's not true in general as I put in comment in answers below. If $f$ is $\mathcal C^2$, then $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac{f''(c_h)}{2!}h^2$ where $|h|<c_h$, and thus, you can control the rest. But as I put in my answer, this machinery is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I know it doesn't really answer your question, but just to avoid this problem, use mean value theorem : there is $t_i^n\in(x_i^n,x_i^{n+1})$ s.t. $$f(x_{i+1}^n)-f(x_i^n)=f'(t_i^n)\Delta x_i^n,$$
and since $f'$ is continuous, you get $$f(1)-f(0)=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}f'(t_i^n)\Delta x_i^n=\int_0^1 f'(t)\,\mathrm d t.$$

Comment: At the end even if it doesn't really answer my question, it answer the general question. So I decided to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hand-wavey solution: Because the number of terms increases at the same rate as the value of the arguments decrease (with $n\to0$). By definition of $o$, the decreasing arguments win out over the increasing number of terms.

Comment: At the end, I'm not so convinced by such an answer, neither by the answer I accepted before. However, I really admit that my question/notations, is not so clear. If you have time, I asked more clearly (and a bit differently) what I had in mind. [You'll find it here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3331103/prove-that-sum-i-0m-n-delta-x-in-varepsilon-i-n-delta-x-in-to-0). I also explained why I'm not convinced. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not true... take $m_n=n$, $\Delta x_i^n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $\varepsilon (h)=\frac{h}{-\log(h)}$. Then $\varepsilon (\Delta x_i^n)=o(\Delta x_i^n)$ but $\sum_{i=1}^n\varepsilon (\Delta x_i^n)\to \infty $.

Comment: @Surb I did say it was hand-wavey. They said they didn't see why something was true. I told them how it is, if not obvious (as you point out, it's not), but how it is very much plausible.