# Prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{m_n} \Delta x_i^n\varepsilon _{i,n}(\Delta x_{i}^n)\to 0$ when $n\to \infty $.

Tags: real-analysis

**Introduction**

This question is inspired from one of my other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325449/prove-that-f1-f0-int-01-ftdt-using-fxh-fxfxhoh/3325826#3325826), and at the end, I'm really not convinced by the answer that I accepted. However, I recognize that the notations are a bit confuse in this previous question. Here, it should be more clear.

---

**Statement**

For all $n$, let $\{x_i^n\}_{i=0}^{m_n}$ a subdivision such that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\sup_{i=0,...,m_n}\Delta x_i^{n}=0,$$
where $$\Delta x_i^n=x_{i+1}^n-x_i^n.$$
Let $\varepsilon _{i,n}:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $\varepsilon _{i,n}(h)=o(h)$ when $h\to 0$. I would like to prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=1}^{m_n}\Delta x_i^n\varepsilon _{i,n}(\Delta x_i^n)=0,$$
for all $i$ and all $n$.

---

**Attempts**

Fix $n\in\mathbb N$. Then, for all $i=1,...,m_n$, there is $\delta _i^n$ s.t. $|\varepsilon _{i,n}(h)|\leq \frac{1}{n}$ whenever $|h|\leq \delta _i^n$. Set $\delta ^n=\min_{i=1,...,m_n}\delta _i^n$. Then $$\sup_{i=1,...,m_n}|\varepsilon _{i,n}(h)|\leq \frac{1}{n},$$
whenever $|h|\leq \delta ^n$.

---

**Problems starts**

Now, I would like to take $N$ big enough to have $$\sup_{i=1,...,m_n}|\Delta x_i^n|\leq \delta ^n,$$ for all $n\geq N$ and thus conclude that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m_n} \Delta x_i^n\varepsilon_{i,n}(\Delta x_i^n)\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{m_n}\Delta x_i^n=\frac{1}{n}\to 0.$$

Nevertheless, I have the impression that it's not correct, because $\delta _n$ could go to $0$ much faster that $\sup_i\Delta x_i^n$, and thus, such $N$ could not exist.

If I could prove that $\inf_{n}\delta ^n>0$, then I just have to take $N$ s.t. $\sup_i \Delta x_i^n<\inf_n\delta ^n$ for all $n\geq N$, but there is no reason to have $\inf_n\delta ^n>0$ (I can really go to $0$).

So, How can I do here ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

**Counter example**

$$\varepsilon _{i,n}(h)=\boldsymbol 1_{\left\{h\geq \frac{1}{n^2}\right\}}(h),$$
and $\Delta x_i^n=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$. Then, $$\sum_{i=1}^{m_n}\Delta x_i^n\varepsilon _{i,n}(\Delta x_i^n)=1,$$
for all $n$.